# Selenium with python does not find specific link

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am looking to scrape a specific link from a website that auto-generates its content via javascript. When I inspect the website manually I can find the link that I want to scrape easily. You can see an example below. Basically, I want to find a way to automatically find the

`<a href="/bsbe/document/JURE210005412/format/xsl/part/L?oi=5wDyMgzh8g&amp;sourceP=%7B%22source%22%3A%22TL%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%22date%22%7D"...>`
tag after the `<li class="toolpane_list_entry toolpane_list_entry_right">`

Example:

```
<li class="toolpane_list_entry toolpane_list_entry_right">
   <a href="/bsbe/document/JURE210005412/format/xsl/part/L?oi=5wDyMgzh8g&amp;sourceP=%7B%22source%22%3A%22TL%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%22date%22%7D" class="button bnext__button button--next bnext__button--next" id="docnextbuttontop" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="id_docPanelContainer">
      <span>
         <span>Nächster Treffer</span>
         <em class="sicon" aria-hidden="true">
            <svg focusable="false" class="svg-icon-chevron_right" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
               <path fill="currentColor" d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"></path>
               <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
            </svg>
         </em>
      </span>
   </a>
```

However, when I load this page with selenium and python, the `<a href...>` I am looking for is not there (see below).

```
<li class="toolpane_list_entry toolpane_list_entry_right">
   <span class="button bnext__button button--nextDisabled bnext__button--nextDisabled">
      <span>Nächster Treffer</span>
      <em aria-hidden="true" class="sicon">
         <svg class="svg-icon-chevron_right" focusable="false" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" fill="currentColor"></path>
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
         </svg>
      </em>
   </span>
</li>
```

As you can see the whole <a href ... > tag is not there.

Here is my python code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium import webdriver

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
firefox_driver = os.getcwd() +"\\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=firefox_driver)
driver.get("https://gesetze.berlin.de/bsbe/document/JURE210005730") 

# returns empty list
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button bnext__button button--next bnext__button--next")


soup_file=driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_file)
print(soup.find_all("li", {"class":"toolpane_list_entry toolpane_list_entry_right"}))
```

Do you know what might be the problem and do you think there is a way to extract the link? Any other information I could provide to find the issue?

Thanks

Comment: You need to include your selenium code

Comment: `driver.page_source` fetches the actual source code of the page, which means before any Javascript has run.  You need to use some of the `find_elements_xxx` methods to plow through the actual DOM of the page.

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried that but it does not work. I tried to find the element by its id and by class and it comes back without anything. In fact, when I list all ids, it is not in there.

Comment: Explain in simple words, what you want to find on this page https://gesetze.berlin.de/bsbe/document/JURE210005730 Your question is difficult to read.

Comment: Which button are you trying to click?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am trying to find the link with the text "Nächster Treffer". In this case it would be: <a href="/bsbe/document/JURE210005412/format/xsl/part/L?oi=5wDyMgzh8g&amp;sourceP=%7B%22source%22%3A%22TL%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%22date%22%7D" class="button bnext__button button--next bnext__button--next" id="docnextbuttontop" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="id_docPanelContainer">

Answer (score 0):

Tried doing this ?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'my-class')]"));
```

in your case , change the `classname` and `tag`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'toolpane_list_entry toolpane_list_entry_right')]"));
```

Comment: Thank you Shabari, I tried driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='docnextbuttontop']") to get directly to the link, but I get a NoSuchElementException. When I try to find the li and the print out the child elements it is also not there, but it shows the same as what I got with beautfulsoup